# High Resolution Web SDK preserve PNG transparency

Tags: aviary, adobecreativesdk

Using High Resolution SDK. Aviary is fully functional on jpg images. As for png images, transparency area are replaced with black when saved. (fileFormat is already set to png). How to preserve transparency when saving edited png files?

[png in editor,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYtgb.jpg)
[png after save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3op5.jpg)

Comment: I found out that Low resolution SDK preserves transparency, whereas high resolution doesn't. Any way to fix this? Thank you Adobe team.

Answer (score 0):

PNG transparency is currently not officially supported by the Creative SDK Image Editor. There is no API to turn on support for transparency using the high resolution API.